# Praxis in Functional Programming

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning about functional programming and come across this way of writing a function:

```
function createCounter (){
  let counter = 0
  return {
    increment: function() {
      counter += 1
    },
    currentValue: function() {
      return counter
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a common way of writing functions in Javascript? I have been programming for at least 3 years and I cannot recall any time. It looks like a mixture of an object and a function. Yes, I know that functions are objects in JS. But I just want to know if this is common and something I should start using at work.

Comment: This is a typical module pattern for exposing public methods. Except it's usually contained in an IIFE for containing context, and written as a function expression rather than declaration.

Comment: Modern javascript has more convenient ways to express this, like classes and modules.

Comment: Yes, this is a very common way to write JS functions - it's a *factory function* that returns an object. Nothing weird about it. And no, there's no mixture between the `createCounter` function and the object(s) returned by it.

Comment: @georg Neither classes nor module do what this function does.

Comment: @Bergi: sure they do: `class Counter {}; ... bla = new Counter()`

Comment: @georg Where do you store the local `counter`, and why does the instantiation require `new`? This is not the same as `createCounter`, and I definitely wouldn't call it "more convenient".

Comment: @Bergi: 1) property, 2) use a factory function if you don't like `new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at how this is being used:

```js
function createCounter (){
 let counter = 0;
 return {
 increment: function() {
  counter += 1
 },
 currentValue: function() {
  return counter
 }
 };
}
  
let counter0 = createCounter();
console.log(counter0.currentValue()); //0
counter0.increment();
counter0.increment();
console.log(counter0.currentValue()); //2
```

As one can see, the `counter0` object exposes two functions, which can be used to read or increment the counter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a somewhat common way, less so in modern code.

However, I would not recommend it if you have the possibility of using ES6/Ecmascript 2015 ([see compatiblity chart](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class)).
Since then **classes** have been introduced to JavaScript and due to similarity to other programming languages I'd say using them provides you with code that's easier to understand.

Example:

```
class Counter {
  constructor(initialValue = 0) {
    // using underscore is common practice to state that it shouldn't be publically accessed
    this._currentValue = initialValue;
  }

  increment() {
    this._currentValue++;
  }

  get currentValue() {
    return this._currentValue;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let counter = new Counter();
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.currentValue); // 1
```

Alternatively you could avoid the getter and just access currentValue like any other (public) variable.
*Edit the code as you see fit to adhere to the practices of functional programming.*

---

Also worth learning:

- Public class variables [arrived in Chrome Jan '19](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/nic72#public-class-fields).
- Private class variables [arrived in Chrome April '19](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/04/nic74#private-class-fields)

Neither of these 2 features work in Firefox today so I'd still hold back on using them unless you compile your code via Babel.